# WAMP 3.1.7 x64 my webpage accessible from anywhere in the world

Tags: wamp

Before I give out my question, I'd like to tell you my reasons of why I need this to work. I am currently making a game and in the future I'll need people to test the game to help me look for bugs. The purpose of this website I am making is to be used as a guide/wiki and for people to report the bugs and later on when the game is near to be open to public, to be the official page with a proper server/domain. With this said, I would like to temporarily have my PC as my webpage server and to be able to allow **only** the IPs of the game testers to connect my PC.

Can someone help me on this, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you created a Virtual Host for this site. If so show your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing your ports publicly on the internet is always **very tricky** because it poses a huge security threat - especially since you just notified the world that you want to do that!

Instead, you should use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), a secure tool used extensively in the industry build specifically for this. It basically serves, in one line of code, a server running locally in a public url looking like `https://<some-code>.ngrok.io`. The only think you'll have to worry about would be hostname mismatch, but believe me, that's still a thousand times easier than to securely expose your personal machine to the internet ;)

Comment: Not the answer that I was looking for but still it's informative and helpful to me. Thank you, will take a look at that.